# how to customize text alignment for different devices using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem using text-alignment class of bootstrap 3. I want my site text-alignment will be changed every time when the view port (devices) change, that is in large device text alignment will be left and small device it will be right, how can i get this? plz help and give an example.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with bootstrap classes, you have to do it with `CSS media queries`:

```
/* xs */
.yourClass { text-align: right; }

/* sm */
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .yourClass { text-align: right; }
}

/* md */
@media(min-width:992px) {
    .yourClass { text-align: left; }
}

/* lg */
@media(min-width:1200px) {
    .yourClass { text-align: left; }
}
```

Use just the necessary media queries. If you want `xs` to be right aligned and from `sm` to `lg` left aligned, just use the `xs` (which is not a media query, remember that Bootstrap 3 is mobile first) and the `sm` one.

**EDIT:**
[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzBne)

Comment: Although when writing the media queries, you can use the LESS preprocessor and the @screen-* LESS variables that Bootstrap provides.

Comment: @azeós can you give me a live example, I got your logic but i cann't implement it when i want to show my site heading text small for small device otherwise large for medium or large devices.

Comment: @Xubayerpantho don't know why, but the jsfiddle example is not working. Here is a CodePen one: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzBne Change the preview size to see the effect.